# mathematical form of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have many sets containing three values like $\{1, -2, 5\}$. 
I am want to write in mathematical form to filter set where exist one value with different sign. (and for sure, none of them should be zero)

I am not sure about tag. (please correct the tag if it is not correct)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you want to filter the sets where not all values have the same sign, that is there exists values of both signs, and zero does not occur. If now $\mathcal A$ denotes your collection of sets, then the filtered collection, which contains only the sets that fulfill your condition is 
$$ \mathcal F =  \{A \in \mathcal A \mid \forall a \in A: a\ne 0 \land \exists a \in A : a < 0 \land \exists a \in A : a > 0 \} $$

Comment: thanks, that's totally fit my desire.

Comment: how can i say all member are positive or negative (for both case not zero)?

Answer (score 0):

How about ($\mathcal M$ is your family of sets) $\mathcal M \cap \left(F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3\right)$, where:
$$F_1 = \{\{a,b,c\} : a,b \in \mathbb R_+, c \in \mathbb R_-\} \\
F_2 = \{\{b,c,a\} : a,b \in \mathbb R_+, c \in \mathbb R_-\} \\
F_3 = \{\{c,a,b\} : a,b \in \mathbb R_+, c \in \mathbb R_-\}. \\
$$